# RDP: How do I set TaskScheduler to automatically log in after being log off?

Tags: tasks

How do I set TaskScheduler to automatically log in after being log off?For example my acc. was log off i want automatically sign in after 10 sec. or 1 min, how to do it?and also restart a tool.bat file too,thank you very much

Comment: Just don't log off? Why would you log off just to sign in automatically seconds later? "Restarting" that `tool.bat` could just be done by either running it through a Task on user login or by putting it into the auto start.

Comment: Other administartors can do that, log off my acocunt or restart the remote

Comment: It's a bad idea to have an account auto sign in. You'd have to hardcode the password etc. it's probably better to either prevent other users from using the machine or changing what ever process needs a logged in user to not have that requirement. Alternatively Windows Server would support having multiple users connected.

Comment: auto sign in only when my acc is loged off and im sleeping and i can't log in and rerun my important .bat file for some 16 hours i will  lose precious time, so when my acc. is log off i want automatically log in after 1 sec or 10 sec and restart automatically my .bat tool

Comment: i want run my .bat day and night with all cost  even if I am away from home 1 year and i can't touch any PC

Answer (score 1):

Running your batch file on login shouldn't be an issue. Either put it in your AutoRun/StartUp for your user or use a windows task to run it.

To create a task look for the `Task Scheduler`, create a new task and as `Action` select `At log on`.

For your other request to automatically login a user I don't think it's possible except right after startup. It would defeat the whole purpose of actually having separate user accounts and you'd have to store your password with that task/script possibly in a readable manner or you'd have to password at all.

If your machine is running a windows client operation system you're most likely out of luck as they only support one concurrent user as far as I know (except Vista Ultimate or something?). With Windows Server you generally can have multiple users logged in at the same time (at least two) so as long as there aren't more users connecting and nobody kicks your connection your tasks would continue to run.

Another option would be to limit the users that actually can use the machine. You can setup the users that are able to use RDP through a dialog in your `Advanced System Properties` on the `Remote` Tab. Administrators could still logon remotely to prevent that check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/598278/how-to-disable-rdp-access-for-administrator).

The best course of action would probably still be to run your task not as your own user but as a service user in the background.